# Is it possible to draw a Google Visualisation Scatter Chart via web workers or similar parallel processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, web-worker

I have a scatter chart that accumulates a lot of data over time, and some critically timed events elsewhere on the page. As the scatter chart accumulates data I'm noticing increasing delays in my timed events due to the increasing load time for the chart.

Is there a way to parallelise the drawing of a Google Visualisation Scatter Chart beside jquery event triggers, such as keyboard and mouse events?

Comment: Web workers cannot access the DOM, so you cannot use them to draw your charts with the Visualization API, but if you have to process your data, you might be able to offload that to a web worker.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect it's the same answer, but how about keydown events within a specific text input? could they be detected in parallel to the rest of the page script?

Comment: Web workers cannot interact with the DOM, so there is no way to make event detection run in parallel.  Once an event triggers, you can offload processing from that event to a web worker (as long as it doesn't involve any DOM interaction).  In theory, you could have a page that only does your events and DOM interactions, and offloads all other tasks to web workers.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any offloadable tasks. All the event triggers do is calculate timing values, which are directly plotted on the scatter plot. Thanks for the help

Comment: If all you have are event handlers that are adding data points to your chart, it doesn't seem likely that you should encounter performance issues (unless you are adding a large number of data points).  You might want to consider doing a performance profile of your application to figure out what is chewing up your CPU cycles.  If that doesn't reveal anything, ask for help here figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: The performance issue is only noticeable because I'm looking at very specific timings between key presses. I want the graph to be updated every time the keys are pressed with a growing 1-D data set of 'time since the previous keypress'. Updating the plot is slowing the completion of the keydown event as the plot takes longer to run, therefore the timing of the keydown events are lagging. We're talking small millisecond changes in timing, but it's critical for the website. Any suggestions for workarounds that allow consistently continuous updates and timing would be appreciated!

Comment: If the root cause is that updating the DOM with the new chart is causing the performance degradation, then there is nothing you can do to parellelize away the problem, as DOM manipulation and events execute in the same thread.  If these millisecond timings really make that much of a difference to your application, then you might be able to alleviate performance issues by issuing draw calls only after `n` events fire, which would improve the accuracy of some proportion of your event timings, with that proportion growing larger as `n` gets larger.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, thanks. Unfortunately it's better for my data model to have repeatable timing so updating every nth would cause bigger issues than the slow increase in timing lag. Thanks for the help, really appreciated. I think it seems unavoidable unfortunately.